# How to change a website localStorage data from browser_action / background

Tags: google-chrome-extension

To start with the problem, the `chrome.storage.local.get` has an **async** that I don't want on the **content_script** when the **run_at: Start**.

So I want to check a storage setting to inject a CSS style into page. The problem with the above is that the page has a flickering when refreshing the page that I don't observed to be with the webstie `localStorage`.

I want to edit the website storage data "localStorage" from the browser_popup that doesn't care about what tab / page is open.

The only way I found is to use the `webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate` and `tabs.executeScript`...
Any more simple idea?

A chat here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/230284/66754336

Comment: You can use chrome.declarativeContent API with RequestContentScript action (the documentation says it's experimental but it's not).

Comment: @wOxxOmI don't see how that would help with anything.

Comment: You would dynamically register/unregister your CSS file so it's applied automatically when enabled instead of making the decision inside the content script.